# Unable to consume a .NET WCF service in Python

Tags: python, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I am trying to access a .NET WCF web service from Python and am getting the following error - would anyone be able to let me know what I am doing wrong:

```
File "C:\temp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\suds\mx\literal.py", line 87, in start
               raise TypeNotFound(content.tag)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: 'authToken'
```

Below is the python code that I have:

```
import uuid
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import, ImportDoctor

url = 'http://something/something?wsdl'
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', location='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd')
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('http://tempuri.org/')
doctor = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(url, doctor=doctor, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'})
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.xsd.schema').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.wsdl').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
client.set_options

myMethod = client.factory.create('myMethod')
myMethod.authToken = uuid.UUID('xxxxxxxx-35f4-4b7b-accf-yyyyyyyyyyyy')
print(f'CLIENT: {client}')
print(f'myMethod: {myMethod}')
ls_Token = client.service.myMethod(myMethod)
print(f'ACCESSTOKEN: {ls_Token}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Create ResponseData object, the type is defined in wsdl, if there are multiple schemas, you need to add a prefix, such as ns0, ns1, etc.

```
ResponseData = client.factory.create('ns1:ResponseData')
ResponseData.token = "Test"
```

Make sure that the properties of the object you created exist,You can view the properties of the object after successfully creating the object.

```
ResponseData = client.factory.create('ns1:ResponseData')
ResponseData.token = "Test"
print ResponseData
```

The following picture is the property of ResponseData object:

[image]

If I use the following code I will get the same error as you:

```
ResponseData = client.factory.create('ns1:ResponseData')
ResponseData.authToken = "Test"
```

[image]

So you need to check whether the myMethod object has authToken property.

Comment: I dont think this worked.                ---- suds.MethodNotFound: Method not found: 'myMethod.WSHttpBinding_ImyMethodSingleRunExecution.__len__'
Unexpected error, recovered safely.

authToken property is there in myMethod()

Comment: Does your WCF service use Wshttpbinding? As far as I know, suds does not support Wshttpbinding. You can modify your server-side binding to basichttpbinding. If you want to use Wshttpbinding, consider Zeep, which is also a Python SOAP client.

Answer (score 1):

We could not get it to work with SOAP WCF and had to modify it to a REST based service to make it work. Python seems to work better with REST service.

Comment: Yes,python's support for SOAP services is not particularly good. For example, the suds you use do not support Wshttpbinding, while WCF Rest services are different. We can use Ajax, java, c#, python to easily call WCF Rest services, client Only need to make an http request.